# Can ROS be played in Windows 10, 64bit?

Tags: windows-10, installation, operating-systems, robots.txt

I try to install ROS(robot operating system) in my computer with windows 10, 64bit.
Is it possible?
And is there any process to do it?

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[ROS on Windows Documentation staging repo](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/).

It contains a link to
[Install ROS on Windows](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/Setup.html).

Note that ROS requires Windows 10 64-bit and using Visual Studio 2017 Community,
Professional or Enterprise.
It also requires [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and Git.

The exact installation method is detailed in the *Install ROS* article.
You will find more informative links in the above *ROS on Windows* article.